# Web Radio Creation Through Node.js

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, webrtc, audio-streaming

I wanted to create my own web radio in node.js, which will include a functionality to create a library by admin. this library will holds sngs in it. while my songs get picked on backend and played on frontend to all connected users. How can I do it?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're question is very broad. but am going to answer the part of audio stream
as below
on you're node js server install a package called `wrtc` which will receive stream from producer and broadcast that stream to other peers which peers uses normal browser/mobile `webrtc` endpoints

Comment: Thanks for your answer, can you please tell me if this broadcaster has a limited number of peers to receive? Secondly, do we require a specific type of web server to handle receiving no of peers in thousands?

Comment: There is no mathematical formula for this but basically just your normal server will do for hundred of users, and for the specific server, its not important as long as you managed to install node js, this `wrtc` is just a node js package

Comment: WebRTC is a peer-to-peer technology. we need to make a file that has a list of songs and one by one these songs get played automatically. or sometimes a brodcaster accesses the mic and broadcast the audio to all connected listners, For this scenario is WebRTC ok? I think that It needs to involve the server for file storage or atleast sending the the video to all connected clients/peers.

Comment: For that case yes, `webrtc` is good candidate for it, but as you know its peer to peer then we need a server to relay this audio plus broadcaster on mic to as well broadcast his voice, for that case there is server side library which enables you to do that its called `mediasoup` which is also built around `webrtc`

Comment: can you please elaborate more on how to use mediasoup in conjunction with webrtc. Thanks, a lot Bro for such knowledge.

Comment: `Mediasoup` is library for node .js, so you going to need to be very good with node js. but basically `mediasoup` is what we call `SFU` which we call `SELECTIVE FOWARDING UNIT` when client side produces media stream, it sent to the server for this case `mediasoup` and `mediasoup` will do a good job of fowarding it to the peers needing this broadcast, plus its flexible. it allows host to speaks on his mic plus you can pipe audio from pretty much any source, - but again. `node js` is biggest requirement on this

Comment: Its documentation havent listed much examples source codes, but there are example projects, you can dig and disect to learn from them

Comment: ok Brother thanks a lot, that was indeed helpful.